# Why do we use geometric distribution here in place of the multiplication rule?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

For the question:

"Only 4% of people have type AB blood. What is the probability we won't find a type AB donor before the 10th person?"

the textbook says to use a geometric distribution. But for the next question: 
"About 8% of male are color-blind. A researcher needs color-blind subjects for an experiment and begins checking potential subjects. What's the probability she finds someone color-blind before checking the 10th man?" it says to use multiplication rule.

How are these different problems? Also, when I use the multiplication rule for the first question, I get a very similar (though slightly smaller) answer. I feel as though I must be missing something obvious—can someone clue me in on why I can't use normal probability rules rule for both?

Comment: Sometimes people who write drill problems for basic probability believe they have a right to specify the method. The 'geometric' distribution is based on the 'multiplication rule' for Bernoulli trials, so the the specifications are not necessarily in conflict. // Properly phrased, you could work the same problems using the binomial distribution: "$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(9, p).$ Find $P(X = 0).$" Does the third problem in sequence say to use the binomial distribution?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by the third problem? These were distinct problems I found but I was confused by why they seem to have the same wording but use different approaches. If binomial distribution can only be used for independent trials, when would we use it in place of the multiplication rule? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe this discussion would be more useful if you showed your solution(s) for various parts. Then one of us might have something additional to contribute to the discussion. // Again: Derivations of both 'geometric' and 'binomial' distributions are based on the multiplication rule for independent Bernoulli trials, so any time you use one of those distributions you are using the multiplication rule (slightly disguised).